# Caterpillar Parts Cross Over

Tags: parts

This may or may not be the right place to ask - but I have searched online already (SKF-VSM and plain old google search), checked my company's internal parts cross over references, and spoke to a CAT dealer (who told me that OEM CAT parts are made by CAT).

So the long and the short of it is. I am applying for a position at CAT and the job calls for a familiarity with CAT suppliers and vendors. I can't find anything online. If anyone has any resources or knows where I could look to see if some of the people and companies I deal with have overlapping business with them that would be wonderful.

In the spirit of clarity I deal with a variety of automotive parts companies (like Timken, Koyo, Dana-Spicer, Meritor, Eaton, etc.).

Again, I realize that this is marginally out of scope for this site. But would appreciate any and all help as I do research for this role.

Comment: They are looking for someone with previous experience with other large equipment manufacturers, this is the only way you could ever become familiar with suppliers in that type of industry, I don't think it can be faked or learned online.

Comment: @Moab, I realize that I already work in a related industry as a Purchaser for a Heavy Duty Automotive chain. However I work in the On-Highway Division, not Off-Highway and I can't ask my colleagues across the hall or someone would figure out that I am looking for work. What I am trying to do here, is see if there are known suppliers that overlap with those I already conduct business with.

Comment: I really think it is off topic here, but will not vote to close as someone may have suggestions for you, good luck on your new job adventure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many divisions in CAT and Yes, we mostly manufacture most of the components in house, However as many automotive manufacturers do , we also have a huge vendor list for smaller components .

Long story short, there is no real way even for someone like me who works inside of CAT to know who the dealers are , I suggest you need to probably get in touch with someone on  of that department.

I would highly suggest getting on Linkedin to build a rapport and going from there.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the insights. This is all stuff that I knew already. I have tried to touch base with people (particularly in Purchasing) but they are equally tight-lipped. I am wanting to apply for a job at within the Finning Division (as a Purchaser) and am hoping to find information about who supplies the PTOs, seals and bearings as I deal with those on the daily at my current job.

Comment: Also, I would +1 your answer, but I spent all of my rep. on the bounty. Sorry :(

Comment: @user007 Its alright! Hope you get the job you are seeking.